# Finding the limit of a definite integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, definite-integrals

> Evaluate:
>   $$
>   \operatorname*{Lim}_{x \to + \infty}
>   \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}
>   \int_{2 \sin \frac{1}{x}}^{3 \sqrt{x}}
>   \frac{3 t^4 + 1}{(t-3)(t^2 + 3)}
>   \,\mathrm{d}t
> $$

I have tried applying the Newton-Leb rule to the integral which becomes a really big equation and the there $\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}x$ of that. I was thinking of applying L’Hospital rule but I’m not sure if I’ll get a right answer with such a big equation. Is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: The main tool you have to apply is the fundamental theorem of calculus: $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x f(t)\,dt=f(x)$.

Comment: But $t$ crosses $t=3$ so is it even defined ?

Comment: @egreg so theres no use of the limits?

Comment: @user568101 Of course they have to be used.

Comment: @egreg lower limit isnt constant in the question as per the formula u sent

Comment: You need to use it twice or use the generalized formula $$\frac{d}{dx}\,\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t)\,dt=f(b(x))\, b'(x)-f(a(x)) \,a'(x)$$

Comment: I think @Empy2 is correct. The function is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

As you know that according to Leibnitz theorem for integrls
$$\frac{d}{dx}\,\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t)\,dt=f(b(x))\, b'(x)-f(a(x)) \,a'(x)$$

> $$\frac{dI}{dx}= \lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{3^5 x^2+1}{9(\sqrt{x}-1)(3x^2+1)}\cdot\frac{3}{2\sqrt{x}}-\frac{3\cdot2^4\sin^4(1/x)+1}{(2\sin(1/x)-3)(4\sin^2(1/x)+3)}\cdot2 \cos(1/x)(-\frac{1}{x^2})\right)$$